# Change content color based on Date Range

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I am building a website using Drupal 7, Views, Rules, Ctools, Panels, etc.

I need to change the content color based on the date. The idea is that each quarter's reports have a different color to make them easier to sort over the life of the student.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: do you mean for a node, block, view - background colour, font colour, title colour?

Answer (score 0):

In your theme, you can implement `hook_preprocess_page(&$variables)` were you can retrieve the currently displayed content (if any) as `$variables['node']`. From there, you can retrieve the value of a date field using [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and use that value to assign classes to the `<body>` of the page in `$variables['classes_array']`.

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (($node = $variables['node']) && ($node->type == 'report')) {
    if ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_report_date')) {
      $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_clean_css_identifier('report-month-' . format_date($items[0], 'custom', 'F'));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider the [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module? From its project page (bold markup added here):

> ... allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
> rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
> path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
> properties.
>
> In combination with Drupal's theme inheritance you can easily achieve features like:
>
> - a **date/time-selected** Christmas theme
> - ...

So by using like 1 theme variation for each quarter you could get the job done, no?